# Converting the contents of a CSV file into a dictionary

Tags: python, function, csv, dictionary

The code I have so far is in a function that basically reads a csv file and prints it's contents:

```
def read(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            print(row)
```

Contents of `sailor.csv`:

```
name, mean performance , std dev
Alice, 100, 0,
Bob, 100, 5,
Clare, 100, 10,
Dennis, 90, 0,
Eva, 90, 5,
```

`read('sailor.csv')` and running the function

current output:

```
['name', ' mean performance ', ' std dev']
['Alice', ' 100', ' 0', '']
['Bob', ' 100', ' 5', '']
['Clare', ' 100', ' 10', '']
['Dennis', ' 90', ' 0', '']
['Eva', ' 90', ' 5', '']
```

required output:

```
{'Dennis': (90.0, 0.0), 'Clare':(100.0, 10.0), 
'Eva': (90.0, 5.0), 'Bob': (100.0, 5.0), 'Alice': (100.0, 0.0)}
```

any ideas how I can achieve that output? Using Python 3.4.2 if that helps, explanation of your answer will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
import csv

def read(filename):
    out_dict = {}
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        next(csvfile) # skip the first row
        for row in reader:
            out_dict[row[0]] = float(row[1]), float(row[2])
            print(row)

    return out_dict

print(read('data.csv'))
```

Prints:

```
{'Bob': (' 100', ' 5'), 'Clare': (' 100', ' 10'), 'Alice': (' 100', ' 0'), 'Dennis': (' 90', ' 0'), 'Eva': (' 90', ' 5')}
```

Not to much to explain here. Just putting the values in the dictionary, and skipping the first row added. I assumed that the persons names are unique.

Comment: His required output has floating point numbers; or maybe it is just ".0" added. And there are no quote marks around the numbers.

Comment: I tweaked it slightly, adding float before row[1] and row[2] fixed the numbers.. now it works perfectly! Thanks!   - no need to use print either as I'll be calling the function later.. read('sailor.csv') works for me!

Comment: @Alex FYI, if you make an edit suggestion, you should provide a more detailed description on *why* you did the edit (rather than *what* you edited)... You don't get to see the comments in the Suggested Edits review; only the post with changes, and the reason you provide; [see this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278894/more-context-in-the-suggested-edits-review) ... You also shouldn't change your question to include the accepted answer; you click "accept" on a question to do that, this keeps the question "clean" for future people with a similar problem who end up here.

Answer (score 8):

using the `csv` standard library and a dictionary comprehension...

```
import csv
with open('sailor.csv') as csvfile:
   reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
   next(reader)
   d = {r[0] : tuple(r[1:-1]) for r in reader}
```

Where `d` will be the dictionary you want. `d[1:-1]` slices the array from the second to the second to last element.

EDIT: skips headers, converts to tuples

Comment: What about the first row: `['name', ' mean performance ', ' std dev']`?

Comment: This is close, but the numbers are meant to be in tuples I think? like so: 'Eva': (90.0, 5.0) not 'Eva': [90.0, 5.0]. 

And 'name': [' mean performance '] is also printed

Answer (score 2):

So... I know this question has mostly been answered, but I thought I'd just throw a one-liner in the mix to add on to the shortening answers:

```
from csv import reader
from itertools import islice

{r[0] : tuple(r[1:-1]) for r in islice(reader(open('sailor.csv')), 1, None)}
```

The only really novel thing is adding `islice` to skip the header row cleanly.

Comment: one thing you missed is making the numbers floats, other than that nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Use DictReader:

```
def read(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            print(row)
```

Comment: wont each row be `{"header1" : val1, "header2" : val2,...}` instead of the tuple / list as shown above?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution if I may:

```
>>> import pyexcel as pe
>>> s = pe.load("sailor.csv", name_rows_by_column=0, name_columns_by_row=0)
>>> s.format(float)
>>> s
Sheet Name: csv
+--------+------------------+---------+---+
|        | mean performance | std dev |   |
+========+==================+=========+===+
| Alice  | 100              | 0       | 0 |
+--------+------------------+---------+---+
| Bob    | 100              | 5       | 0 |
+--------+------------------+---------+---+
| Clare  | 100              | 10      | 0 |
+--------+------------------+---------+---+
| Dennis | 90               | 0       | 0 |
+--------+------------------+---------+---+
| Eva    | 90               | 5       | 0 |
+--------+------------------+---------+---+
>>> del s.column[''] # delete the column which has '' as its name
>>> s.to_dict(True) # make a dictionary using row names as key
OrderedDict([('Alice', [100.0, 0.0]), ('Bob', [100.0, 5.0]), 
('Clare', [100.0, 10.0]), ('Dennis', [90.0, 0.0]), ('Eva', [90.0, 5.0])])
```

Here is the documentation on [pe.load](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/generated/pyexcel.load.html#pyexcel.load) and [to_dict](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/generated/pyexcel.Sheet.to_dict.html#pyexcel.Sheet.to_dict) of pyexcel